# Python 3.3.1 While Loops

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to write a while loop here is my code (homework so its basic):

```
import random
RandomNumber=(random.randint(0,100))

GuessedNumber=int(input("Guess any whole number between 0 and 100! "))

while RandomNumber != GuessedNumber:
    if GuessedNumber==RandomNumber:
        print("Well done you gessed correctly!")
    else:
        print("Unlucky guess again!")
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong with my while loop, help would be appreciated; thanks.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: i dont understand how to get my while loop working basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never update the value of `GuessedNumber` inside the loop.  Therefore, if the code enters the loop, it will never leave it because `RandomNumber != GuessedNumber` will always be true.

You need to do something like this:

```
import random
RandomNumber=(random.randint(0,100))

GuessedNumber=int(input("Guess any whole number between 0 and 100! "))

while RandomNumber != GuessedNumber:
    print("Unlucky guess again!")
    GuessedNumber=int(input("Guess any whole number between 0 and 100! "))

print("Well done you gessed correctly!")
```

Notice how the value of `GuessedNumber` is now updated with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: just what a needed thanks much appreciated.